# missing values when creating training and testing data with caret

Tags: r, statistics, r-caret

My question is about how handle missing values when using train for fitting models with caret.
A small sample of my data would be like that:

```
       df <- dput(dat)
       structure(list(LagO3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 40, 45, NA), RH = c(69.4087524414062, 
       79.9608383178711, 64.4592437744141, 66.4207077026367, 66.0899200439453, 
       91.3353729248047), SR = c(298.928888888889, 300.128888888889, 
       303.688888888889, 304.521111111111, 303.223333333333, 294.716666666667
       ), ST = c(317.9917578125, 317.448253038194, 311.039059244792, 
       312.557927517361, 321.252841796875, 330.512212456597), Tmx = c(294.770359293045, 
       294.897191864461, 295.674552786042, 296.247345044048, 296.108238352818, 
       294.594430242372), CWTE = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), CWTW = c(0, 0, 
       0, 0, 0, 0), o3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 52, 55, NA)), .Names = c("LagO3", 
       "RH", "SR", "ST", "Tmx", "CWTE", "CWTW", "o3"), row.names = c("1", 
       "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

The problem is that for several positions in one of my predictors I have NA and the predictand (o3) has also NA (but in different positions). Then, I tried:

```
model <- train(x = na.omit(x.training), y = na.omit(training$o3), method = "lmStepAIC",
               direction="backward", trControl = control)
```

But, I would have different length for y ...
I tried to use:

```
 model <- train(x = x.training, y = training$o3,na.action=na.pass, 
                method = "lmStepAIC",direction="backward",trControl = control)
```

having the following error:

> Error in quantile.default(y, probs = seq(0, 1, length = cuts)) :
> missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

I would appreciate any suggestion!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `na.action` argument with **`na.omit`** of the `train` function. As the documentation says for `na.action` (type `?train`):

> A function to specify the action to be taken if NAs are found. The default action is for the procedure to fail. An alternative is na.omit, which leads to rejection of cases with missing values on any required variable. (NOTE: If given, this argument must be named.)

So the following will work:

```
model <- train(x = x.training, y = training$o3, 
              method = "lmStepAIC",direction="backward", 
              trControl = control, na.action=na.omit)
```

Output:

```
> model <- train(x = x.training, y = y.training, method = "lmStepAIC",direction="backward",
+                na.action=na.omit)
Start:  AIC=-129.7
.outcome ~ LagO3 + RH + SR + ST + Tmx + CWTE + CWTW


Step:  AIC=-129.7
.outcome ~ LagO3 + RH + SR + ST + Tmx + CWTE


Step:  AIC=-129.7
.outcome ~ LagO3 + RH + SR + ST + Tmx


Step:  AIC=-129.7
.outcome ~ LagO3 + RH + SR + ST


Step:  AIC=-129.7
.outcome ~ LagO3 + RH + SR


Step:  AIC=-129.7
.outcome ~ LagO3 + RH


Step:  AIC=-129.7
.outcome ~ LagO3


Step:  AIC=-129.7
.outcome ~ 1
...
...
...
```

Comment: I know, I tried it, but I still the error:   Error in quantile.default(y, probs = seq(0, 1, length = cuts)) : missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE . I don't know why na.action is not working here...thanks!

Comment: @user3231352 All I can see in your code is `na.pass` not `na.omit`. It will definitely work with `na.omit`. Mine performed the StepAIC perfectly. I ll post the output. Maybe it's your control file then. Let me know what the control function is and what is your call please by editing your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I checked it without control and it seems to work (but, with a warning: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :There were missing values in resampled performance measures.). The problem still happens when I use the control, which is just: control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number=10). But since, I wanted to do the cross-validation, I should use this. I don't know what I am doing wrong, I am trying different things to handle the NA, but it is not working...thanks again for the help.

Comment: If you do a cross validation in which case you might end up with just NAs in one of the resamples just treat NAs outside the train function. Type `training <- na.omit(training)` to get rid of NA rows (same way that the function really works in the argument of train) and try that. Or try replacing the NAs with something else if you can (again outside the function). There is no other way.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the advice, I think in this way could work! Thanks again!